# if/switch statement based on a select value and array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a simple select element with multiple values which basically groups in to four categories. To try and be more efficient I thought it would be best to group them in to arrays and check if the "selected" value is in one of them, printing different text based on which arrays the select value is in. 
Also wouldn’t be more efficient to do it with a switch?

Maybe it's a bit vague. User starts with a dropdown with multiple values(for example: x1,y2,x3,y4,z1) I could wright a statement if x1,x3 then do something, if y2,y4 then do something. But I thought that it would cleaner to put those values in to arrays (for example arrayX = x1,x3 and arrayY=y2,y4.) so the script would check which array contains selected value, and print a custom message for each array.

After some tinkering,this a working example:

```
  $( "#search2" )
        .change(function() {
            var group1 = ['PL'];
            var group2 = ['AD','RS','CH'];
            var group3 = ['AT','BE','BG','HR','CY','CZ','DK','EE','FI','FR','GR','ES','NL','IR','IS','LT','LU','LV','MT','DE','NO','PT','RO','SK','SI','SE','HU','GB','IT'];
            var group4 = ['SM','MC','LI'];
            var group5 = ['QQ'];

            $("#search2 option:selected").each(function () {
                str2 += $(this).val();
                if ($.inArray(str2, group1) !== -1) {
                    groupNr ="1";
                }
                else if ($.inArray(str2, group2) !== -1) {
                    groupNr = "2";
                }
                else if ($.inArray(str2, group3) !== -1){
                    groupNr = "3";
                }
                else if ($.inArray(str2, group4) !== -1){
                    groupNr = "4";
                }
                else if ($.inArray(str2, group5) !== -1){
                    groupNr = "5";
                }
            });
            if($('#search2').val()){
                $('#submit').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        })
        .trigger( "change" );
```

Comment: does the code work? if so http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for it

Comment: Depends on how much data there is.

Comment: @depperm didnt know about coder review(thx), but no it dosent work.

Comment: @epascarello there will be about 40 options to select. But still I dont know how to get the value that the user selected from the drop down and compare it with an array:/

Answer (score 0):

Their is an easier way. you cna have an array and assign to each value a group. like

```
mygroupArray['IA'] = 1,     mygroupArray['KS'] = 1
mygroupArray['MN'] = 2 and so on
```

then you can do something like this

groupNumber = mygroupArray[optionValue] === undefined ? 4: mygroupArray[optionValue]

This is the quicker and easy way. Since you do only one comparison. But is a bit more on initialization.

Please let me know if you understood.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach, full working JSFiddle added:

```
var groups = [
    ['IA', 'KS'],
    ['MN', 'OK'],
    ['KE']
];

for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++)
{
    if (groups[i].indexOf(optionValue) >= 0)
    {
        $('.result2').text('element in group ' + (i+1));    
    }
}
```

Check the complete JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/orvvyrhp/1/

UPDATE: JSFiddle with multi-select support: https://jsfiddle.net/orvvyrhp/2/

Comment: ok, thx for you help but I dont realy understand the mechanics? As I've mentioned It's connected to a dropdown where the user can select multiple values. Instead of printing exact value I need to group them in to 4 categories so if a user selects it will print a custom text for the group.

Comment: @MichałKorzeniowski, multi-select? But is this multi-selection always in 1 group? If yes, then to check if one of the multi-select is in a group.

Comment: no sorry I got mixed up. I've updated my original post.